# What does it mean by a 1/25 chance for a Solar Eclipse to happen?

Tags: terraria

I know a Blood Moon event has a 7/72 chance of occurring each night. But a Solar Eclipse can happen any time during the day. So I've heard it has a "1/25 chance" of happening, but how often does it check that?

Comment: Maybe 1/25 - 4% chance each night?

Comment: Every morning, but yes, 4% chance each day, calculated at the crack of dawn. (4:30 am)

Comment: I've edited your question to more clearly state what I think you're asking. If this isn't what you meant, you can revert the changes by clicking [edit].

Answer (score 2):

### Whether a Solar Eclipse occurs is only determined at dawn

A [Solar Eclipse](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Solar_Eclipse) has a 1/20<sup>1</sup> chance of occurring each day, and lasts the entire day. Whether or not a particular day will have a Solar Eclipse is checked once at dawn, not at multiple points during the day. This is the same way a Blood Moon is determined, being checked once at dusk and lasting the entire night.

<sup>1</sup>The Wiki page says 1/20, but the [history](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Solar_Eclipse#History) indicates that the chance of a Solar Eclipse happening was supposed to have *decreased* from the former 1/25 in the 1.3.0.4 patch, so I can't tell which number is actually right.